# facebook like does not read og:properties

Tags: facebook, properties

I have some pages with profiles and articles with content generated from php and mysql. My code about facebook is: (everything else is ..........)

```
<head>
.....
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://xxxxxxxx?profile.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $imagename;?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="xxxxxxxxx" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
.....
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
..............
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://xxxxxxxxx/profile.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>;" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
................
</body>
```

1) facebook like takes content from my index page and in facebook debugger i get the mistakes:

```
 Inferred Property: The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
 Inferred Property: The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

2) facebook admin number is ok

3) php generates the content ok. I checked the page code from the browser

any suggestions??

Comment: Is you page visible from outside, aka is it on public domain or on you local computer? Because facebook can't get to you local comp to parse page html.

Comment: no my page is on a server and is visible..

Comment: Hmmm, maybe something else is bloking it. New domain not progated to all dns, .htaccess rule etc.

Comment: well i made a test page that worked well until i got an id to change the content.. i mean that facebook could not read /test.php?id=something!!! thats what i must find out why...

Comment: hey guys sorry but i had a stupid syntactic mistake!!! thank you for your answers and sorry i posted but i'm trying to debug this for 3 hours! :P

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
In addition, we've extended the basic meta data to add a required field to connect your webpage with Facebook:

fb:app_id - A Facebook Platform application ID that administers this page.
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Try adding that tag as well and see if that helps.

Also, make sure that the URL is properly encoded:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: thanks for your help, it was a stupid syntactical mistake in url!